# finding union/intersection of sets using Node

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have two Node

```
Node set1;
Node set2;

set1 = {'a','b','d','1'};
set2 = {'1','c','d'};
```

I need to find the union and intersection of these two sets. so they should look like This

```
union = {'a','b','c','d','1'};
intersection = {'1','d'};
```

I'm trying to avoid using arrays. I can iterate through my Nodes like this

```
while(set1.hasNext){
char ob = set1.next;
}
```

I've also made a method that gives the length of the sets. `set1.length();`
In my real implementation sets are huge and they are not all char. There are some generic types and they are all in the Node linked list as objects. so I'm trying to avoid using arrays.Help please!!!

Comment: Use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), or, by "avoid using arrays", do you mean avoid using arrays and anything else that's not a linked-list, specifically of type `Node`? If so, it might be a good idea to sort them first, if possible.

Comment: I can use linked list...but not continuous arrays..and I don't need sorted order I have method that takes care of that after...

Comment: Well, you could either sort them first and do the intersection and union from there, or you can just concat them and then sort, removing the duplicates. Either way ... ummm ... what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a `Set` from the java collections framework?  Implemented with a `HashSet`?  For Union you could just do an `addAll` call to do union.  And for intersection you could just iterate through the smaller set and see if the bigger set `contains` each element.  For each element in both sets you can add it to your intersection set.